# list files from directory between given hours using linux command

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, find

There are few errors which we need to mitigate which can be done only when I am able to find the list of files which got created between 2 hours.

My file naming pattern is

```
App_ErrorFile1401_01_11_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_1234_123456.csv.gz
```

I need to find files which are between 9AM-11AM of yesterday. Having found the list of files I will then FTP those files to a given server IP.

FTP part is something which we can do easily but I am not able to find any pattern using which I can search only 2 hours files and select them for FTP. I dont have much idea of grep with regex pattern and after going through net for more than an hour I am yet to figure out how to build my statement. 
I can use find/grep. I am on RHEL.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for for files with the naming pattern or files created/modified/accessed/etc during the stated period?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code snippet if you can use bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define timearea
yesterday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%Y%m%d")
start="${yesterday}090000"
stop="${yesterday}110000"

find . -name "App_ErrorFile*.csv.gz" | \
while read -r file; do
    IFS=_ read -r -a arr <<< "$file"
    timestamp="${arr[4]}"
    if [[ $timestamp -ge $start && $timestamp -le $stop ]]; then
       echo "$file"
    fi   
done
```

You have to start it from the directory in which the files are located.